# Is there a way to restrict a user from editing their own Information on Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

I have a database full of users. Each user has a score value that represents their score in a leaderboard. Now I can easily use the firebase security rules to prevent other people from changing the score of that user. But how can I prevent the user from editing their own score in the database without preventing the program from being able to update the users score? The problem is that it is easy to edit a users data in the Browser console. How can this prevented?

Here is the code that sets the value of user score:

```
function setUserValue(uid, type, value) {
    var userRef = new Firebase("https://bragr.firebaseio.com/users/" + uid
            + "/" + type);
    userRef.transaction(function(currentValue) {
        return value;
    });
}
```

If I call the function like so:

```
setUserValue(user.id, "score", 10);
```

That users score is set to 10 in the Database. This should be allowed. However I am trying to prevent the user from being able to simply type this into the console and hack their score.

Here is the structure of the DB:

```
355e3361-a124-491e-8c2b-239893b5cf62:
--- email: "test@test.com"
--- score: 50
--- username: "Stacker"
```

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. Because, I just put an update command into the browser console, and it changed the value on the DB

Comment: @Ian OP is talking about Firebase, not a relational DB.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin ah, you are right, my apologize..

Comment: @SidneydeVries If you rely on the rules of the client program to produce a "valid" score increment, there is unfortunately no way to distinguish between a compromised client sending fake score increments and valid score increments. However, if it is instead possible for an external observer to keep score using the data being updated by the clients, disqualifying invalid or suspicious data, you can write an privileged agent to do this. Depends on what kind of game it is, would need more information to comment further.

Comment: The score is calculated based on a series of other objects in the database. So your suggesting to just calculate the score value based on those?

Comment: Show you data structure, the code you'd like to allow and a snippet of code you'd like to reject. Without those, it's hard to understand the problem.

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I would suggest to write rule to prevent write normal user to score and use REST or node.js to update score using firebase secret token ( so it'll override security rules ).